# Android studio - Can't find newly added internal assets

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, assets

When trying to use any newly added assets I get the error:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: bg.png (Internal)
```

The code is fine, since if I try to use an asset I added a few days ago it works fine. The naming is correct, and there are no capital letters or anything like that.

For some reason AS is not registering the newly added assets.

I've tried cleaning, synching and rebuilding, I've tried several files, nothing works.

What could be causing this?

Comment: restarting android studio may help..!!

Comment: I've tried that several times too, problem started yesterday.

Comment: Try creating new project then..!!

Comment: MAYBE YOU MUST CLEAR YOUR CACHE

Comment: Tried all suggestions, nothing worked. I'm currently updating everything related to AS, see if that helps.

Comment: Show us the line where you are asking for `bg.png`, your folder structure to that image and your working directory. It should just work...

Comment: @MennoGouw I cloned my repo to a new project, and now it works. No idea what caused it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
|__Run
   __Edit Configuration
   (in the left side)
     __Default
       __Application
```

In the right side choose `Configuration` tab . Under `Working directory` specify your android/assets path.

Comment: Already set the working directory, ive been able to add assets the last 9 months Ive been working on this project, now it just stopped working